# How to retrieve a list of nodes not already commented by a user with a specific role

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to make an administration view (visible only for user with role = moderator) that simply lists all nodes in my site that doesn't have any MODERATORS comment.

Please notice that I'm not asking to show all nodes with zero comments, but list all nodes not already commented by users with moderator role.

Thank you in advance for helping me.